# Wait for try-catch complete before move on (Javamail authentication)

Tags: android, multithreading, passwords, try-catch, jakarta-mail

So here is the problem, I need to check if the password *user inserted* is correct for his gmail by performing a send action. But the application has to catch the exception from google server so it can *raise the flag* and then the main activity will act according to that flag(the result string). But some how the application doesn't wait for the try catch block to complete so it goes through all code lines before the flag is changed.

```
public class MailSender {
    String author = null;
    String address = null;
    String subject = null;
    String textMessage = null;
    String result = null;
    Session session = null;
    protected String checkPass(final String myEmail, final String myPass) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(myEmail, myPass);
        }
    });
    CheckPass task = new CheckPass();
    task.execute();
    return result;
}
public void getResult(String result)
{
    this.result = result;
}
class CheckPass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String myResult = null;
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("p2pteamtaskmanagement@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("p2pteamtaskmanagement@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("test check pass");
            message.setContent("message", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);                
        } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            myResult =  "Wrong password";
            return myResult;
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myResult =  "ok";
        return myResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        getResult(result);
    }
}
}
```

this is a part of the main activity

```
reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (eName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {
                MailSender myMailSender = new MailSender();
                String test = myMailSender.checkPass(tUser.getText().toString(), eName.getText().toString());
                if (test == "Wrong password") {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                MyAsync ma = new MyAsync();
                ma.execute();
                intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT_INTENT, tUser.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(NAME_INTENT, eName.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Or someone help me if there is an easier way to check if a gmail password is correct using Javamail.

Thanks and sorry for my English as well as my code manner.

Comment: You should also fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncTask is used to do things in the background **asynchronously**. This means that the thread you execute the task from will continue execution after starting the task. You'll wait for the task to complete before you check whether the authentication has succeeded.